# Minimum Levenshtein distance

Tags: python, c++, levenshtein-distance

how to calculate the minimum distance between a set of rows
the input is supplied with lines (25 in total), you need to find the lines with the minimum distance and specify the distance itself.
what I do

```
file = open('input.txt')
bio = []
for i in range(N):
    a = file.readline().strip()
    bio.append(a)
distance = 0
min_d = 0
dop_l_1 = []
dop_l_2 = []
for i in bio:
    list_d = []
    for j in range(len(bio)):
        distance = distance_1(i, bio[j])
        list_d.append(distance)
    res = nsmallest(2, list_d)[1]
    ind = list_d.index(res)
    dop_l_1.append((i, bio[ind]))
    dop_l_2.append(res)
    if min(dop_l_2) == 1:
        break
mini = min(dop_l_2)
m = dop_l_2.index(mini)
m_2 = dop_l_1[m]
fout = open('output.txt', 'w')
print(bio.index(m_2[0]) + 1, bio.index(m_2[1]) + 1, mini, file=fout)
```

distance_1 - the function calculates the distance between two rows

my implementation is too slow is there a way to find from a set of rows two that have the minimum distance, except by passing through all the rows in turn

Comment: Why do you have a 10 MB memory limit? If input.txt is larger than 10 MB, you exceed that right at the beginning.

Comment: Did you write a unit test, or can you write an assertion which proves that the distance function actually works?

Comment: I didn't really understand about the memory, I think it's not the size of the input, but the memory that python spends. This is a training task with a test, I have one test and the distance works. test added to the question. with this option, when I get to the 5th test (I don't have it) and I'm given Time Limit.

Comment: Please try to solve one part in one language at a time, don't dump your whole homework here for us to sort out. If you have concrete problems, ask a concrete question with a [mcve] here. Further, Thomas Weller didn't say it explicitly, but use "Test Driven Development" (TDD)! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].